# Gas Error when I try to deploy a bnb rewards contract on testnet

Tags: solidity, testnets, bsc

I made a contract - code here: [code link](https://www.codepile.net/pile/1rYVwp8j)

Contract Compiles.
Now I have tried to deploy on BSC testnet and it failed with:

```
Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below).
The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?
Internal JSON-RPC error. { "code": -32000, "message": "execution reverted" }
```

mapping contract appears to deploy correctly

What is the cause of this error?

Comment: thanks, this has solved the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the router address

```
    IUniswapV2Router02 _uniswapV2Router = IUniswapV2Router02(0x10ED43C718714eb63d5aA57B78B54704E256024E);
```

is not a contract in bsc testnet.